# What is replacement for mongodb oplog in aws document db to listen to changes in collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, aws-documentdb

We use oplog collection(that is present in local database) in our code to check if an event happens on a specific db and fire an event in our code.But,as aws document db doesn't support oplog as mentioned in "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/developerguide.pdf",how can we do that?Is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use oplog even with your local mongodb. This is a deprecated approach. The modern way is to use Change Streams, which is supported by Amazon DocumentDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html

Comment: For more on changes streams in Amazon DocumentDB, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html